# Render circle with gradient in OpenGL / OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm using C# and OpenTK for graphics, which is basically a wrapper around OpenGL.

I'm currently rendering a circular ocean behind the circular planet, and it looks like this:
[image]

What I would really like to do is render the ocean with a gradient, so the deepest part of the ocean is darker and it gets lighter as it goes up. Additionally, I'll be using a similar approach with the atmosphere and that will be a fade to 0%. I'd like this approach to work properly with a circle of any radius -- small or large.

All I would know to do is render a serious of circles of larger radii and reducing opacity or darker color. I'm sure there's a better way. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT 6-18-2018:
Here's how to render the disk. Just need the gradient now.

```
    private void DrawDisc(Vector2 center, float innerRadius, float outerRadius, Color4 fillColor)
    {
        // no one knows what this is
        var quad = Glu.NewQuadric();

        int segments = 10;

        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_BLEND);
        Gl.glBlendFunc(Gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, Gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        Gl.glColor4f(fillColor.R, fillColor.G, fillColor.B, fillColor.A);

        Glu.Disk(quad, innerRadius, outerRadius, segments, segments);

        Gl.glEnd();
        Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_BLEND);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1. Use a [shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) that computes the color of each rendered pixel. Explaining what shaders are and how to use them is to broad to answer here, but there is plenty of documentation about that. Essentially, such a pixel shader would compute, for each pixel of the disc, its distance from the center and/or the ocean depth and produce a color based on that. You can define whatever equation you like at that point.
2. Use a texture that has the desired image and add texture coordinates to your disks in order to map the texture on them. The texture will then stretch or shrink with the disks.